# Issue with macro clearing formulas and not cleaning up text in excel

Tags: excel, vba

The below macro is set to run every sheet but my main sheet. After it runs my formulas in column C are gone and the clean up section never ran, so there is access text in each row.

```
    Sub testV2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

     ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Macro" Then

    Columns("A:A").Select

    Selection.Replace What:="*identified", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="as*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False


ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

         Columns("A:A").Select
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

With ws.UsedRange
  .Value = .Value
End With


    End If
    Next ws
    End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me... You don't even touch column C in your code. There is no code to clear formulas. What do you mean by "there is access text in each row"? Also, @LMM9790 has a good point, you need to activate the sheets if you are looping through them. But your question still doesn't make a lot of sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you didn't activate the currently used sheet to remove the duplicates from it. That way ActiveSheet always refers to the sheet that was selected when you started running the code. Does it work with the following code?

```
Sub testV2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

     ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
         If ws.Name <> "Macro" Then

        Columns("A:A").Select

        Selection.Replace What:="*identified", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Selection.Replace What:="as*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False


        ws.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

        Columns("A:A").Select
        Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

         End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: ok that resolved the issue of it not running on the sheets after the refresh. but the issue of it clearing the formulas out of column C it still there not sure why it does that. As Vacip said there is no refrence to column C

Comment: Column C on which sheet?

Comment: on every sheet save the main sheet there is a formula in column c that needs to remain, it tallys the difference between the import and a static column

Comment: Okay, so the formulas in column C include values from column A?

Comment: Correct column A is the import

Comment: The problem should be fixed now in the above posted code. The problem was the inclusion of the code `With ws.UsedRange
  .Value = .Value
End With` which replaced all formulas in the cells by the values of the cells.

Comment: You sir are amazing it worked perfectly ! Thank you I've been stuck on that one for a good bit now.

Comment: You're welcome, if you could just mark this as correct it will help others having this question to save time since it is already solved. Thanks